# HSSFWorkbook - Como copiar uma planilha para outra?

Tags: java, microsoft-excel, apache-poi

Tenho uma planilha de *excel* que preciso copiar alguns dados para uma outra planilha. Essa planilha antiga é como uma "base", preciso copiar apenas a parte de cabeçalho e legenda (com o estilo da célula, além do texto).

Estou utilizando a biblioteca *HSSFWorkbook*, porém estou com dúvidas de como prosseguir.

Vi no [stackoverflow ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903539/how-to-copy-a-excel-sheet-into-another-workbook-using-apache-poi-for-java) o código, porém achei o meio confuso

---

```
abaOrigem = origem.getSheetAt(0);
abaDestino = destino.createSheet(abaOrigem.getSheetName());

for (int indiceLinha = 0; indiceLinha < 5; indiceLinha++) {
    copiarLinha(abaOrigem, abaDestino, destino, indiceLinha);
}
```

O erro que aparece:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at testeExcel.CopiaXLS.pegarValorCelula(CopiaXLS.java:102)
    at testeExcel.CopiaXLS.copiarLinha(CopiaXLS.java:63)
    at testeExcel.CopiaXLS.copiar(CopiaXLS.java:30)
    at testeExcel.app.main(app.java:14)
```

Comment: Não é mais fácil você fazer a cópia do arquivo como um todo?

Comment: não.. pq esse arquivo meio que um "arquivo base", ele tem dados que não será utilizados na nova planilha porém outros dados serão copiados.

Comment: Então melhora um pouco a sua pergunta colocando o formato que está o arquivo e algumas informações adicionais, como o código que você tentou até então...

Comment: reescrevi a pergunta! valeu pela dica ;D

Comment: Você quer copiar completamente uma aba?

Comment: na planilha existem 2 abas, a primeira aba quero só o cabeçalho (as primeiras linhas). Na segunda aba quero ela completa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Criei uma classe para realizar o que você quer baseada [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33881684/3388148):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import static org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType.BLANK;
import static org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType.NUMERIC;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook;

public class CopiaXLS {

  public static void copiar(String caminho) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
    String extensao;
    Workbook origem;
    Workbook destino;
    Sheet abaOrigem;
    Sheet abaDestino;
    File arquivoDestino;

    extensao = caminho.substring(caminho.lastIndexOf("."), caminho.length());
    origem = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(caminho));

    if (extensao.toUpperCase().equals(".XLS")) {
      destino = new HSSFWorkbook();
    } else {
      destino = new SXSSFWorkbook();
    }

    // Primeira aba
    abaOrigem = origem.getSheetAt(0);
    abaDestino = destino.createSheet(abaOrigem.getSheetName());

    copiarLinha(abaOrigem, abaDestino, destino, 0); // Copia o cabeçalho

    // Segunda aba
    abaOrigem = origem.getSheetAt(1);
    abaDestino = destino.createSheet(abaOrigem.getSheetName());

    for (int indiceLinha = abaOrigem.getFirstRowNum(); indiceLinha < abaOrigem.getLastRowNum(); indiceLinha++) {
      copiarLinha(abaOrigem, abaDestino, destino, indiceLinha); // Copia o cabeçalho
    }

    origem.close();
    arquivoDestino = new File(caminho.substring(0, caminho.lastIndexOf(".")) + " - Cópia" + extensao);
    destino.write(new FileOutputStream(arquivoDestino));
    destino.close();
  }

  private static void copiarLinha(Sheet abaOrigem, Sheet abaDestino, Workbook destino, int indiceLinha) {
    Row linhaOrigem;
    Row linhaDestino;

    linhaOrigem = abaOrigem.getRow(indiceLinha);
    linhaDestino = abaDestino.createRow(indiceLinha);

    for (int indiceCelula = linhaOrigem.getFirstCellNum(); indiceCelula < linhaOrigem.getLastCellNum(); indiceCelula++) {
      Cell celulaOrigem = linhaOrigem.getCell(indiceCelula);
      Cell celulaDestino = linhaDestino.createCell(indiceCelula);
      CellStyle estiloDestino = destino.createCellStyle();

      definirValorCelula(celulaDestino, pegarValorCelula(celulaOrigem));
      estiloDestino.cloneStyleFrom(celulaOrigem.getCellStyle());
      celulaDestino.setCellStyle(estiloDestino);
    }
  }

  private static void definirValorCelula(Cell celula, Object valor) {
    if (valor instanceof Boolean) {
      celula.setCellValue((boolean) valor);
    } else if (valor instanceof Byte) {
      celula.setCellValue((byte) valor);
    } else if (valor instanceof Double) {
      celula.setCellValue((double) valor);
    } else if (valor instanceof String) {
      if (((String) valor).startsWith("=")) { //  Formula String
        celula.setCellFormula(((String) valor).substring(1));
      } else {
        celula.setCellValue((String) valor);
      }
    } else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
  }

  private static Object pegarValorCelula(Cell celula) {
    switch (celula.getCellTypeEnum()) {
      case BOOLEAN:
        return celula.getBooleanCellValue(); // boolean
      case ERROR:
        return celula.getErrorCellValue(); // byte
      case NUMERIC:
        return celula.getNumericCellValue(); // double
      case STRING:
      case BLANK:
        return celula.getStringCellValue(); // String
      case FORMULA:
        return "=" + celula.getCellFormula(); // Fórmula
      default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
  }
}
```

Para executar você utiliza o seguinte método:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
    CopiaXLS.copiar("C:/meu arquivo.xls");
  } catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Teste.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  } catch (InvalidFormatException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Teste.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
}
```

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta, me ajudou muito já, porém ainda tenho uma dúvida. No método copiar, na parte da primeira aba eu quero copiar as 5 primeiras linhas e não só a primeira. Porém quando eu faço essa modificação, ou utilizo o mesmo for que vc fez para a segunda aba, aparece o erro java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @MariTeixeira fez o `for` de 0 até 4? Consegue disponibilizar o `XLS` pra avaliarmos?

Comment: poxa... o xls é do meu trabalho, não posso passar mas sim, fiz o for até o 4

Comment: @MariTeixeira complicado. Em qual linha dá a exceção?

Comment: o erro que aparece está na resposta abaixo

Comment: @MariTeixeira sem o arquivo impossível te ajudar mais que isso. Infelizmente não dá pra saber o que tem de errado na célula para poder tratar isso.

Comment: fiz um arquivo bem parecido com o que eu quero utilizar... como faço pra te mandar e vc vê? Consigo adicionar o arquivo por aqui (sou nova no stack)

Comment: @MariTeixeira você pode colocar ele no google drive ou qualquer outro lugar que te dê um link pra baixar depois e colocar o link na sua pergunta

Comment: o upload de arq é bloqueado aqui, mas fiz uma planilha no Planilhas Google aí é só exportar.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nAQCpJgDGwHAk-d80jpmpOxXFlSIql2l_PTvWKjXqKM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @MariTeixeira testei aqui e com essa planilha que você upou funciona normalmente

Comment: é... acho que é um erro no arquivo, pq copiei e colei em outro arquivo e foi. Muito obrigada @sorack

Comment: @MariTeixeira tranquilo. Eu vou atualizar minha resposta para suportar `XLSX` também. Um detalhe: Colunas mescladas não funcionam corretamente nesta solução. Caso a resposta tenha lhe atendido não esqueça de marcá-la como escolhida para que outras pessoas com a mesma dúvida possam se beneficiar também.